# Why Hazelcast is fast?

Tags: java, database, hazelcast

I have several years of experience of working with code related to databases, but there was one question I always asked myself. How Java-based Hazelcast (in-memory) can be faster than any another non-Java based database? For example, in-memory Redis and Memcached are not based on Java.

I heard a lot of negative stuff about Java and its JVM which slows down code 10-1000 times comparing to non-VM environments. Does that mean that everything has changed within time? I know it's now lot better than few years before, but it still has performance decrease because of its obvious idea "working on every platform". So how can Java code suddenly be faster than non virtual machine code or **even same speed**?

Comment: `but it still has performance decrease because of its obvious idea "working on every platform"` The reasoning is that the later you optimise, the more you know about the code. JVMs optimise code at runtime, and that optimised code is very much platform-specific. (That's the theory at least.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Research the JVM and how it "slows down code 10-1000 times". FUD statement is FUD.
- "DB speed" isn't just platform, it's implementation and features.
- The Hazelcast website has info regarding implementation, avoiding GC, architecture, etc.